# Retrieving Mobile Connect Contacts Using Java Fuel API

Tags: mobile, java, fuel-sdk

How can I get these contacts from the mobile connect app using the java fuel api?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer to my question.

I have'nt figured out how to built in the filter for the data extension yet but you can loop throught the return values and pick it out manually.

```
ETResponse<ETDataExtension> response = client.retrieve(ETDataExtension.class);
            for (ETDataExtension etDataExtension : response.getObjects()) {
                System.out.println(
                " ID:" + etDataExtension.getId() +
                " Key:" + etDataExtension.getKey() +
                " Name:" + etDataExtension.getName()+
                " Description:" + etDataExtension.getDescription() +
                " Create Date:" + etDataExtension.getCreatedDate()+
                " Modified Date:" + etDataExtension.getModifiedDate());


                ETResponse<ETDataExtensionRow> etDataExtensionRowResponse = etDataExtension.select();
                List<ETResult<ETDataExtensionRow>> etDataExtensionRow = etDataExtensionRowResponse.getResults();

                for (Iterator iterator2 = etDataExtensionRow.iterator(); iterator2.hasNext();) {

                    ETResult<ETDataExtensionRow> etResult2 = (ETResult<ETDataExtensionRow>) iterator2.next();

                    Map<String, String> row = etResult2.getObject().getColumns();

                    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> entries = row.entrySet().iterator();
                    while (entries.hasNext()) {
                        Map.Entry<String, String> entry = entries.next();

                        if (etDataExtension.getName().contains("The Name of you data extension.")) {
                            System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: @Justin Apostolellis

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the filter as a SQL WHERE like string, e.g.:

```
ETResponse<ETDataExtension> response = client.retrieve(ETDataExtension.class,
                                                       "name = 'this is a test'");
```

or

```
ETResponse<ETDataExtensionRow> response = dataExtension.select("value >= 42");
```

-ian